# for loop to iterate through even numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays

I thought the following should do it - but doesnt seem so.

```
int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7};
        for(int k=0;k<jokes.length && jokes[k]%2==0;k++){
            System.out.println(jokes[k]);
        }
```

Evaluating within the function will work anyways - but wanted to check if there would be a way to filter the search within the for loop definition itself (maybe by calling a function in the loop definition itself?)
Would be very cool if we could achieve that.

Comment: Your array index starts with 0. Have you taken care of that?

Comment: The condition part of the for loop defines when the loop should stop. If you just want even numbers then incrementing by two should help. To choose the numbers that are even in the list you have just put the 'evenness' condition in an if statement.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 for(int k=0; k< jokes.length; k+=2){ 
     System.out.println(items[k]); 
   }
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wanted I don't think. He is looking to check if an item in an array is even or not.

Comment: It's not if you look at his code but if you read the title it seems to be what he asked for

Comment: I know, titles can be confusing. +1 in case anyone finds themselves here trying to do what the title says.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to overcomplicate things.

```
int[] jokes = new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7}
for(int k = 0; k < jokes.length; k++){
    if(jokes[k] % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(jokes[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if (jokes[k] & 1 == 0)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will continue until `k < jokes.length && jokes[k] % 2 == 0` is false.
So, for your example input, it will exit immediately.

You need to put the check inside the loop:

```
int[] jokes = new int[] { 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7 };
for (int k = 0; k < jokes.length; k++) {
    if (jokes[k] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(jokes[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try That

```
int[] jokes = new int[] { 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7 };

for (int k = 0; k < jokes.length ; k++) {
    if (jokes[k] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(jokes[k]);
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7};
for(int k=0; k<jokes.length; k++){
    if(jokes[k]%2 == 0){
        System.out.println(jokes[k]);
    }
}
```

Do the check inside the loop in order to allow the `for` statement to iterate through the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

The second condition in your `for` loop will make the loop stop as soon as it sees a odd number in jokes[k].  So I would rewrite it to:

```
    int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7};
    for(int k=0;k<jokes.length;k++){
        if (jokes[k]%2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(items[k]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to inrease `k` by 2 every iteration step?

```
for(int k=0; k<jokes.length; k+=2){
    System.out.println(items[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed code.

```
    int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7};
    for(int k=0;k<jokes.length;k++){
        if (jokes[k]%2==0) {
               System.out.println(items[k]);
        }
    }
```

Examine it. It is very simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the `jokes` array but printing `items[k]` which is **another array entirely**. This should do.

```
        int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7,2,10,-2,-1};
        for(int k=0;k <jokes.length ;k++){
            if(jokes[k] % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(jokes[k]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but the below code could do the trick. Note that the the System.out.println shoud have jokes[k] instead of items[k]

```
        int[] jokes=new int[]{5,7,8,9,3,4,6,1,7};
        for(int k=0;k<jokes.length;k++){
            if (jokes[k]%2==0)
                System.out.println(jokes[k]);
        }
```